# Popular browser plugin prevent tracking mailto: clicks on my website

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, google-tag-manager

I configured trigger in Google Tag Manager which should fire a tag when "Click URL contains mailto:". The code on site is:

```
<a class="ikonki" href="mailto:hello@wro.place"><img src="http://www.wro.place/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/icon-Mail.png" width="80" height="80"></a>
```

The tag is not fired when browser extension [Mailto: for Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mailto-for-gmail/dgkkmcknielgdhebimdnfahpipajcpjn) or similar is active. Deactivating extension results in tag firing properly. How can I fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Add click event same as following sample. make sure bind event after document is ready make sure jquery is loded.

```
$(function(){

    $("a[href^='mailto:']").click(function(){
    alert("I CLick");
});

});
```

Comment: Thanks for getting involved Pankaj, but I have no idea how to implement this solution. Could you explain it to me in more detail please?